# How to have multiple files with one module?

Tags: module, rust

I don't understand why we have only one file per module.

```
// main.rs

mod dog; // Find dog in dog.rs or dog/mod.rs
fn main() {
    dog::sonic_bark();
}
```

When `dog` grows larger and has lots of functions, it's not good to have all of them in one file.

How I can separate them without using

```
dog::leg::walk();
dog::head::nose::smell();
dog::tail::iron_tail();
dog::mouth::sonic_bark();
```

I want to just use `dog::sonic_bark();`

Comment: This should be struct but I just ask about module.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot.

You can have *more* modules than files (the typical examples being `mod tests` nested in the file), but not the reverse.

---

However, this does not matter because you can use encapsulation + re-export.

The default when declaring a submodule with `mod xxx;` is that `xxx` is *private*: no user of the current module will know that it depends on `xxx`.

Combine this with selecting re-exporting symbols:

```
pub use self::leg::walk;
pub use self::head::nose::smell;
pub use self::tail::iron_tail;
pub use self::mouth::sonic_bark;
```

And you can call those directly: `dog::walk()`, `dog::smell()`, ...

Therefore, private imports and public re-exports help you have a *hidden* internal hierarchy while exposing a flat public interface.

---

Complete example:

```
mod dog {
    pub use self::head::nose::smell;
    pub use self::leg::walk;
    pub use self::mouth::sonic_bark;
    pub use self::tail::iron_tail;

    mod leg {
        pub fn walk() {}
    }

    mod head {
        pub mod nose {
            pub fn smell() {}
        }
    }

    mod tail {
        pub fn iron_tail() {}
    }

    mod mouth {
        pub fn sonic_bark() {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    dog::sonic_bark();
}
```

Comment: Where to put re-exporting symbol ?

Comment: I knew it now. Put in mod.rs. I just researched.

Comment: Also you can reexport all public items from a module directly: `pub use self::leg::*;` etc

Comment: Can you show the example solution across multiple files? The original question was asking about how to split the modules into multiple files and its not clear for this example how to do that.

Answer (score 7):

It *is* possible, but you should **absolutely not do this** because it's unidiomatic, will probably break various tools and IDEs, and is just generally confusing. Please don't read this except for educational purposes.

---

The trick is to use [`include!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html) to directly import source code.

**Filesystem**

```
do-not-do-this
├── Cargo.toml
├── src
│   ├── dog-head.rs
│   ├── dog-tail.rs
│   ├── dog.rs
│   └── main.rs
```

**src/main.rs**

```
mod dog;

fn main() {
    dog::bark();
    dog::wag();
}
```

**src/dog.rs**

```
include!("dog-head.rs");
include!("dog-tail.rs");
```

**src/dog-head.rs**

```
pub fn bark() {
    eprintln!("Woof");
}
```

**src/dog-tail.rs**

```
pub fn wag() {
    eprintln!("Swish");
}
```